# How to search a specific array determined by a variable?

Tags: javascript

Being quite new at JavaScript, I'm assuming the answer to my question is extremely simple and I just don't know what I'm doing, but here goes:

How do I write an if statement that checks the value of an array when the array name is determined by a variable.

For example, say I've got something like this:

```
$x = 2

arr1 = [1, 1]
arr2 = [2, 2]
```

and I want to determine which array I examine based on the value of x.  The way I'm trying it is below, but I'm quite certain that isn't right:

```
if (arr$x = 1)
alert ('2)
```

Comment: Check your code. I think you mean something like `if (arr$x[0] === 1) {alert ('2');}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know arrays - put them to use. An array can contain *anything*, including other arrays. Just store those two arrays in a third ("two-dimensional") array and use `$x` as index.

Note that the example comparison will be false anyway, as you're comparing an array (i.e. multiple values) to an integer (i.e. a single value).

Answer (score 2):

Use the scope you're in. If you defined your array in the global scope (i.e. `window`) you can use window['arr'+$x]. If you're within a (pseudo)namespace like:

```
var myNamespace = {
  arr1: [1,2],
  arr2: [3,4]
}
```

You would retrieve arr1 with `myNamespace['arr'+$2]`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need a two dimensional array:

```
var x = 1;
var arr = Array();
arr[0] = ['1', '1'];
arr[1] = ['2', '2'];
alert(arr[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var conditionX = true; //when conditionX is true, search arr1 otherwise search arr2

var arrayToSearch = null;
var arr1 = [1, 1];
var arr2 = [2, 2];

if(conditionX)
{
   arrayToSearch=arr1;
}
else
{
   arrayToSearch=arr2;
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's rather verbose and limited to choosing from two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`window["arr" + $x]` works fine in place of `arr$x` in your code.

Also, you should be using `==` in your `if` statment, `=` is for assignment.

Comment: Only if the `arr*` variables are global. And even then it's not a real solution, just a crutch if you're for some weird reason unwilling to use a two-dimensional array or at least an object to look up from via string.

Comment: @delnan fair enough, I thought OP might want a general answer to "how do I access variables whose names are dependent on the contents of other variables"

Comment: Even if, the right answer would still ne "you don't, you make it a hash table or array lookup".

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** oops... looks like i am too late =X

You would be trying to use a multidimensional array, so here is an example

```
var arr = []; 
arr[0] = [1,2,3];
arr[1] = [4,5,6];
arr[2] = [7,8,9];

//Chose an array to examine
var choseArr = 1;
alert( arr[ choseArr ] );
```